# html readonly attribute not removable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to remove the readonly attribute from the following input field:

```
<input id="cno" name="cno" type="number" class="form-control" readonly />
<button type="button" id="no-edit" class="btn btn-warning">Edit</button>
```

I have tried using jQuery(1.11) to remove the attribute on the click of a button.

```
$("#no-edit").click(function() {
   $("#cno").removeProp('readonly');
});
```

And I have also tried using:

```
 $("#no-edit").click(function() {
   $("#cno").removeAttr('readonly');
});
```

Please help! I don't understand why it fails.

Comment: It works as it supposed. Did you include jquery library? http://jsfiddle.net/rR5Jr/

Comment: Of course there'd be also the non-jQuery way: `document.getElementById('cno').readonly = false;`

Comment: Also from [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/removeProp/): "Do not use this method to remove native properties such as checked, disabled, or selected. This will remove the property completely and, once removed, cannot be added again to element. Use .prop() to set these properties to `false` instead."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#no-edit").click(function() {
   $("#cno").prop('readonly', false);
});
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7BynH/)

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it on document.ready worked for me.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#no-edit").click(function() {
           $("#cno").removeAttr('readonly');
       });
})
```